# Ansible: need to combine information from 2 files for a task later

Tags: ansible

I'm running Ansible 2.7.9 on Red Hat Linux 7.4. In my playbook, I need to combine information in two yml files into one data structure that I can then iterate over in a task.

For example, in one .yml file I might have:

```
---
network_interfaces:
  big_computer:
    - name: eth0.10
    - name: eth1.20
    - name: ens224
    - name: bond1
      type: bond
      device: intel
```

In another .yml file called definitions.yml I might have:

```
---
eth0.10:
  type: vlan
  slave: true
  master: bond1
  subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
eth1.20:
  type: vlan
  slave: true
  master: bond1
  subnet: 192.168.20.0/24
ens224:
  type: ethernet
  subnet: 172.19.22.0/23
bond1:
  type: bond
```

I am able to set, for example, a variable `network_interfaces_list` from `network_interfaces[computer_type]`

When `computer_type` is `big_computer`, then, I want to take the names of `network_interfaces_list`, the data from `network_interfaces_list`and the data from `definitions.yml`, and create this combined data structure. Then use that data structure in a task. Note that some information may be included in the `network_interfaces` file, but some of it is found in the `definitions` file. Or it may remain undefined- there is no "slave" or "master" setting for the `bond1` interface, for example.

network_interfaces_list should end up looking like this:

```
-  eth0.10:
    type: vlan
    slave: true
    master: bond1
    subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
- eth1.20:
    type: vlan
    slave: true
    master: bond1
    subnet: 192.168.20.0/24
- ens224:
    type: ethernet
    subnet: 172.19.22.0/23
- bond1:
    type: bond
    device: intel
```

Entries missing in a dictionary for any given list item are considered unimportant for that item and are essentially null.

I've been wracking my brains all day on this one. I can debug either entry, but trying to put them together- especially without Ansible giving me errors about missing dictionary keys- I'm finding impossible to do.

Essentially what I want is a short file of information, and for those items that are considered unimportant at first glance, I want to put them in another layer that we can peruse to gather more detail, if we wish.

I have done this successfully:

```
- debug:
    msg: "interface_list: {{ network_interfaces_list }}"

- name: MIKE debug
  debug:
    msg: "thingy: {{ interface['name'] }} \
                  {{ interface['type']|default('NULL') }} \
                  {{ interface['device']|default('NULL') }}"
  loop: "{{ network_interfaces_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: interface

- name: MIKE2 debug
  debug:
    msg: "thing2: {{ lookup ( 'vars', interface['name'], default='XXX' ) }}"
  loop: "{{ network_interfaces_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: interface
~~~

But I'm stuck in trying to get merge the members of `interface['name']` from the two data structures.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        network_interfaces_list: "{{ network_interfaces_list|default([]) +
                                     [{item: _val}] }}"
      loop: "{{ _keys }}"
      vars:
        computer_type: big_computer
        _keys: "{{ network_interfaces[computer_type]|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
        _vals: "{{ network_interfaces[computer_type] }}"
        _dict: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"
        _val: "{{ _dict[item]|combine(definitions[item]) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  network_interfaces_list:
  - eth0.10:
      master: bond1
      name: eth0.10
      slave: true
      subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
      type: vlan
  - eth1.20:
      master: bond1
      name: eth1.20
      slave: true
      subnet: 192.168.20.0/24
      type: vlan
  - ens224:
      name: ens224
      subnet: 172.19.22.0/23
      type: ethernet
  - bond1:
      device: intel
      name: bond1
      type: bond
```

---

**Notes**

- The dictionaries keep the redundant attribute *name*
- The names of the variables in definitions.yml are not valid. See [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). Include them in a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: definitions.yml
        name: definitions
```

gives

```yaml
  definitions:
    bond1:
      type: bond
    ens224:
      subnet: 172.19.22.0/23
      type: ethernet
    eth0.10:
      master: bond1
      slave: true
      subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
      type: vlan
    eth1.20:
      master: bond1
      slave: true
      subnet: 192.168.20.0/24
      type: vlan
```

- In some cases a dictionary might be a better structure, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        network_interfaces_dict: "{{ network_interfaces_dict|default({})|
                                     combine({item: _val}) }}"
      ...
```

would give

```yaml
  network_interfaces_dict:
    bond1:
      device: intel
      name: bond1
      type: bond
    ens224:
      name: ens224
      subnet: 172.19.22.0/23
      type: ethernet
    eth0.10:
      master: bond1
      name: eth0.10
      slave: true
      subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
      type: vlan
    eth1.20:
      master: bond1
      name: eth1.20
      slave: true
      subnet: 192.168.20.0/24
      type: vlan
```

Comment: vladimir-botka, that's some serious Ansible-fu. Where did you learn how to juggle varibles like that? Any websites that are helpful, or other resources? @Vladimir Botka

Comment: Just practice. FWIW see my collection of [examples](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples). Thank you for the comment.